# Django 1.5 Generic view

Tags: django, django-views, django-1.5

I'm practicing django with "Practical Django 2nd edition" book, which is based on django 1.1
I installed django 1.5 so I should figure out the changes between django's versions and write the right code (thanx django documentation)

Generic views changed a lot in django 1.5 but finally I got it. I have four urls in my urls.py as below:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/$', EntryYearArchiveView.as_view(), name='coltrane/Entry_Archive_year'),
    url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/$', EntryMonthArchiveView.as_view(),name='coltrane/Entry_month_Archive'),
    url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
        EntryDateDetailView.as_view(), name='coltrane/Entry_Date_Detail'),
    url(r'$', ArchiveIndexView.as_view(model=Entry, date_field="pub_date"), name='coltrane/Entry_Archive'),
)
```

and views for each url. As you can see **ArchiveViewIndex**'s url is just a $ sign so the address
`example.com/weblog/` should run this. And the EntryYearArchiveView gets a year.
but something is wrong! the address of `example.com/weblog/2013/` still runs **ArchiveIndexView** but not **EntryYearArchiveView**. The **EntryMonthArchiveView** goes wrong too. The name of YearArchive template is **Entry_archive_year** as supposed to be.
What I'm messing here?

Comment: are you passing in the year `2013` as a number or as a string?

Comment: I just followed the book. I think it's a number because (?P<year>\d{4}).

Comment: it should have taken it fine. Just try one thing for me - change the last url to `r'^$'` instead of `r'$'`

Comment: That's it. Thanx a lot. Now it runs right view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marking comment as an answer for future reference.

change the last URL from

```
url(r'$', ArchiveIndexView.as_view(model=Entry, date_field="pub_date"), name='coltrane/Entry_Archive'),
```

to

```
url(r'^$', ArchiveIndexView.as_view(model=Entry, date_field="pub_date"), name='coltrane/Entry_Archive'),
```

for it to match URL patterns correctly.